# Get an array of 4 elements with RxJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Trying to get data from firebase, but grouped 4 by 4. How would I manage to group and return an observable of 4 in 4.

```
# input
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

# output
# [ [1,2,3,4], [5, 6, 7, 8]...]
```

I have tried this, but it only takes the first 4 and returns an array and not as an observable

```js
this.data$ = this.afs
      .collection<Data>('data')
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(take(4), toArray());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `bufferCount`

```js
this.data$ = this.afs
  .collection<Data>('data')
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(bufferCount(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're explicitly making the return type an array by using `.pipe(take(4), toArray());`. Try removing the second parameter `toArray()`.

Comment: that works, but it only takes the first 4 and not more

Comment: See @Mrk Sef's answer. I was in the process of writing the same!